# Control flow python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, infinite-loop

Actually I am used to c++ and I am stuck in python. I can't seem to understand what's causing the infinite while loop.
The main goal of the code is to calculate how many months are required to save enough money for upfront payment.

```
#*******Initializing all the required variables***********
home_price = float(input("Enter the price of your dream home:")) # cost of the home

down_payment_portion = 0.25 # initial upfront pay for the home which is 25%
stamp_duty_portion = 0.03 # 3%

annual_salary = float(input("Enter your annual salary:"))

tax_portion = 0.2 # 20%
save_amount = 0

save_portion = float(input("Enter the amount of money you want to save after tax-cut:"))

annual_return = 0.05 # 5%
months = 0

#*********************************************************
#------------Calculating all the necessary values---------

down_payment_portion = down_payment_portion * home_price # calculating the down payment for the dream home

stamp_duty_portion = stamp_duty_portion * home_price # calculating the stamp duty for the home

tax_portion = tax_portion * annual_salary # calculating the tax cut

save_portion = save_portion * save_amount # calculating the portion of tax-cut income to be put into savings

annual_return = (save_amount * annual_return) / 12

upfront_payment = down_payment_portion + stamp_duty_portion

while(save_amount < upfront_payment):
   save_amount = save_amount + annual_return
   save_amount = save_amount + (annual_salary - tax_portion) * save_portion / 12
   months = months + 1

print(f'You will need {months} month to save enough for your upfront payment{upfront_payment}.')
```

Comment: Print the value of `save_amount` and `upfront_amount` at each iteration inside `while` loop, you'll know what the issue is

Comment: Yeah it is an infinite loop I tried that

Comment: I am not saying whether it's infinite or not, By printing those values, you'll actually know the reason for infinite loop, I said that.

Comment: I see, the value of save_amount is always 0, it's not increasing

Comment: Now try to figure out why it's always 0 and never increasing.

Comment: Consider using a debugger and you will find your logic error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You initialise `save_amount = 0`
2. you get `annual_return` as `annual_return = (save_amount * annual_return) / 12` which would be **zero**
3. you also get `save_portion` as `save_portion = save_portion * save_amount` which is again **zero**
4. Therefore your `save_amount` in the **while loop** is never incremented it too remains **zero**, `save_amount < upfront_payment` is always true ==> Infinite loop

In your code

```
while(save_amount < upfront_payment):
   save_amount = save_amount + annual_return # 0 + 0 = 0

   # 0 + (some value * 0)/12 = 0
   save_amount = save_amount + (annual_salary - tax_portion) * save_portion / 12
```

Comment: What a silly mistake I made. Anyways thank you so much!!